# Getting ArgumenError while trying to create instance of a ruby class

Tags: ruby, oop, encapsulation, argument-error

I am trying to improve my OO ruby skills. I've created a class and when calling and trying to make ans instance of it, I get error.

Here is the code.

```
class EncapsulatedPerson
    def initialize(name)
        set_name(name)
    end

    def name
        @first_name + " "+ @last_name
    end

    def set_name
        first_name, last_name = name.split(/\s+/)
        set_first_name(first_name)
        set_last_name(last_name)
    end

    def set_first_name
        @first_name = name
    end

    def set_last_name
        @last_name = name
    end

end
```

when I load the file, which I wrote above lines into, and attempt to create instances of this class

```
2.2.0 :004 > ep = EncapsulatedPerson.new('William Wallace')
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
  ... #
```

As I understand from error, I should pass 0 arguments when creating new instance (However I believe `def initialize(name) ...` necessiates one (name) argument'

```
2.2.0 :003 > ep = EncapsulatedPerson.new
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
```

I've totally confused. How many arguments does `new` method require when trying to instantiate it? One argument or no argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say, that the error of `number of arguments (1 for 0)` is caused by your `set_first_name` and `set_last_name` methods, which are declared not to accept any arguments:

```
class EncapsulatedPerson
  # ...

    def set_first_name
        @first_name = name
    end

    def set_last_name
        @last_name = name
    end

end
```

Try updating them, so they accept arguments:

```
class EncapsulatedPerson
  # ...

    def set_first_name(name)
        @first_name = name
    end

    def set_last_name(name)
        @last_name = name
    end

end
```

Hope this helps!

**EDIT**

The complete code should look like:

```
class EncapsulatedPerson
  attr_reader :first_name, :last_name

  def initialize(name)
    set_name(name)
  end

  def name
    @first_name + " "+ @last_name
  end

  def set_name(name)
    first_name, last_name = name.split(/\s+/)
    set_first_name(first_name)
    set_last_name(last_name)
  end

  def set_first_name(name)
    @first_name = name
  end

  def set_last_name(name)
    @last_name = name
  end

end

epa = EncapsulatedPerson.new('William Wallace')
puts epa.first_name
```

Comment: thanks for attempt but still having same problem

code is here - http://repl.it/rzK/2

Comment: ... and the same for `set_name` too.

Comment: @marmeladze - I've just updated your code you provided. `set_method` also should accept `name` argument + you need to add `attr_reader :first_name, :last_name` to be able to access the attributes. Please be aware, tah your second object wont be intialized as `name` is required argument

Comment: @undur_gongor's tip solved it. not only `set_first_name` and `set_last_name`, also `set_name` posesses same problem. thanks to all you! :)

Comment: actually no need for attr_reader. making set_name, set_first_name, and set_last_name private methods will encapsulate class very well.

Comment: Actually, `attr_reader` creates "getter" methods, so if you want to be able to access `first_name`, like in your example: `epa.first_name`, you need to implement it on your own, or let the `attr_reader` do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Oh Dear, your class definition is wrong, change `set_first_name` and `set_last_name` methods in `EncapsulatedPerson` like this.

```
def set_first_name(name)
    @first_name = name
end

def set_last_name(name)
    @last_name = name
end
```

Comment: thanks for your efforts but still having same issue
check here - http://repl.it/rzK/2

Answer (score 1):

In the initialize method, you are calling `set_name` method which accepts 1 argument :

```
def initialize(name)
    set_name(name)
end
```

whereas your `set_name` method definition doesn't accept any arugument :

```
def set_name
    first_name, last_name = name.split(/\s+/)
    set_first_name(first_name)
    set_last_name(last_name)
end
```

As per you design since the method `name` is already created as an instance method, no need not pass it as an argument to `set_name`.

But I would say you should modify your class as shown below.

To fix your issue, change the class like this :

```
class EncapsulatedPerson
  def initialize(name)
    @first_name, @last_name = name.split(/\s+/)
    set_name(@first_name, @last_name)
  end

  def name
    @first_name + " "+ @last_name
  end

  def set_name(first_name, last_name)
    set_first_name(first_name)
    set_last_name(last_name)
  end

  def set_first_name(first_name)
    @first_name = first_name
  end

  def set_last_name(last_name)
    @last_name = last_name
  end

end
```